# Ubuntu 13.10 - VirtualBox Win7 x86? or Win7 x64?

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my Sony Vaio and got rid of Win8 :P

Now at work; I need to use some software in windows; so I guess the best idea is to install a VirtualBox - Win7 machine.

My question is: Should I install Win x86?? x64??

Which one will run faster and consume fewer resources??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my experience it's about the same performance wise, but according to various microsoft documents I've seen the 64bit version apparently consumes more ram for the system cache. I don't have cite handy.